# Can I have bulk delete in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I want to delete more than one id by entering it as an array, but it doesn't work, why?
that's my code

````
      name: 'Test 2: hard delete test',
      condition: { id:[5,6,7]}
    },
  
  ];

  const hardDeleteTestResults = [];

  for (const test of hardDeleteTests) {
    try {
      // const user = await User.destroy();
      const user = await User.findByPk(
        test.condition.id);
        
   
      const deleteUser = await User.destroy({
        where: test.condition,
        force:true
        });

      const hardDeletedUser = await User.findOne({
        where: test.condition,
     
      }); ```
````

Comment: What do you mean by `deosn't work`? Any errors? How does the generated SQL query look like? Can you add it to the post?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this will solve your problem:

```js
import { Op } from "sequelize";
const deleteUser = await User.destroy({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Op.or]: [5, 6, 7]
    }
  }
});
```

You can read up on querying and using operators in a where clause [in the docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#the-basics).

In the future, please make sure to:

- Describe your problem in more detail. (Full code snippet, error output)
- Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen.